# How to use shell to print every line containing the first col in the file where the number of occurrences of the first col exceeds K times

Tags: shell

**Source File**

```
$cat log.txt

key1 1654684897 1 3 d d
key1 1654684897 1 3 d 2038
key1 1654684997 1 3 c c
key1 1654684997 1 3 c 2038
key1 1654684997 1 3 c 2071
key2 1654684897 1 3 d d
key2 1654684897 1 3 d 2039
key3 1654684997 1 3 c c
key3 1654684997 1 3 c 2038
key3 1654684997 1 3 c 2071
```

my solution:

```
$cat log.txt|awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c |awk '$1>2{print $2} |xargs -I{} grep -E {} log.txt
```

**Output**

```
key1 1654684897 1 3 d d
key1 1654684897 1 3 d 2038
key1 1654684997 1 3 c c
key1 1654684997 1 3 c 2038
key1 1654684997 1 3 c 2071
key3 1654684997 1 3 c c
key3 1654684997 1 3 c 2038
key3 1654684997 1 3 c 2071
```

**Because my log file is very large, this method is too time-consuming, is there a faster method?**

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: There are methods, but I don't think anyone would *recommend* doing this in shell rather than a scripting language meant for this task.

Comment: So, it would probably help if you also, aside from telling us where exactly you're stuck, also told us your current approach and the scripting languages you feel somewhat comfortable with – nobody will do your work for you here, but we can lead you on the way and equip you with the right knowledge. You've not shown an approach to solve the shortcomings of your current solution (you only show the bad current solution)

Comment: ```cat log.txt|awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c |awk '$1>2{print $2} |xargs -I{} grep -E {} log.txt ```

Comment: yes, that's your current approach.

Comment: grep scans the entire file every time, is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make two passes over the file in awk, one to count keys, one to print lines that qualify:

```bash
awk 'NR == FNR { keys[$1]++; next }
     keys[$1] > 2' log.txt log.txt
```

Comment: thanks, this solution is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this:

```
awk '{ORS=","}NR == FNR { keys[$1]++; next } 
     keys[$1] >= 100 && ++a[$1] <= 100 
     {if (a[$1]==1){print $1;  for(i=3;i<=NF;++i) print  $i}
     else if (a[$1]<100) {for(i=3;i<=NF;++i) print  $i } 
     else {for(i=3;i<=NF;++i) print  $i; print "\n" } }' 
     log.txt log.txt | sed 's/^,//' >>result
```

log.txt has 137,002,531 rows, and result has 190,992 rows.

It only took 2 minutes and 56 seconds